# How to set maxLines to FlowRow in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a design requirement where we have a [`FlowRow`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow) type of layout with multiple labels that are placed one after the other, and if labels occupy more than two lines, we just truncate at that.
So something like this:

[image]

If I configure maxLines to 2, if there are more labels overflowing to line 3, then don't show them.

In a `FlowRow`, truncating by the amount of elements is super easy, like:

```
        FlowRow(
            modifier = ...
        ) {
            showItem(items.first())
            showItem(items.second())
            if items.length > 2 then showIndicator()
        }
    }
```

However to truncate on the amount of lines you need to measure the components and know how many lines they're taking giving the content you have.

Compose's `FlowRow` doesn't expose the measure policy nor line count so I cannot really tweak this and writing my own `Layout` sounds like overkill. Copying the measure policy and tweak it seems like the only option, but I wonder is there a better way??

Using `modifier.height` in `FlowRow` is not acceptable as that won't scale well.

Worth clarifying, the row doesn't scroll horizontally.

I found this issue in [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/269961555), but it's not shipped yet.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Configuring `FlowRow` with `maxItemsInEachRow = items.size / maxLines + 1` worked for me

Comment: TY for the suggestion! As discussed, that should work if `FlowRow` is scrollable. I edited the question to clarify in this case it's not scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing a simple custom `Layout`, got inspired by a similar impl I found on [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/flow-layout-in-jetpack-compose-5586cd1e0f03).

```
        val measurePolicy = flowLayoutMeasurePolicy(maxLines)

        Layout(
            measurePolicy = measurePolicy,
            content =
            {
                items.forEach {
                    ChipItem(it)
                }
            },
            modifier = modifier
        )
```

where the measure policy is:

```
private fun flowLayoutMeasurePolicy(maxLines: Int) = MeasurePolicy { measurables, constraints ->
    layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
        var lines = 0
        var yPos = 0
        var xPos = 0
        var maxY = 0

        for (index in measurables.indices) {
            val rest = constraints.maxWidth - xPos
            // if there's enough space left, try to fit one more pill in the current row
            val isEnoughSpace = rest >= (0.4 * constraints.maxWidth)

            val measurable = measurables[index]
            val placeable = if (isEnoughSpace) {
                measurable.measure(Constraints(maxWidth = rest))
            } else {
                measurable.measure(Constraints())
            }

            if (lines == maxLines) {
                break
            }

            if (xPos + placeable.width > constraints.maxWidth && !isEnoughSpace) {
                yPos += maxY
                xPos = 0
                maxY = 0
                lines += 1
            }

            if (lines < maxLines) {
                placeable.placeRelative(
                    x = xPos,
                    y = yPos
                )
            }

            xPos += placeable.width

            if (maxY < placeable.height) {
                maxY = placeable.height
            }

        }
    }
```

Notice I try to fit in another chip in the same row if the remaining space is around 40% or more.

I'm thinking this could be be optimised with `SubComposeLayout`, as we dont want to compose every item if we're only showing a few (which is the canonical use case).

Also we could add some calculations to determine if it is the last line and more items are overflowing, to add a composable indicating this.

This is how it behaves, when limited to two rows, and the text in the chip items are set to overflow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should now be fixed in 1.7.0-alpha03

[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#FlowRow(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FlowRowOverflow,kotlin.Function1))

```
@Composable
@ExperimentalLayoutApi
FlowRow(
    modifier: Modifier,
    horizontalArrangement: Arrangement.Horizontal,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical,
    maxItemsInEachRow: Int,
    maxLines: Int,
    overflow: FlowRowOverflow,
    content: @Composable FlowRowScope.() -> Unit
)
```